# How to mount servlet.jar in the classpath of an integration test run by Ant (that also uses Jetty and RestAssured)

Tags: junit, ant, jetty, embedded-jetty, rest-assured

I've a project https://github.com/paul-hammant/helloworld-war (fork of someone else's, value added).  It's a really quick build, and should serve as a demonstration of integration tests for teams that have not flipped to Maven/Gradle etc.

It has an integration test that brings up Jetty, and runs an Integration test that uses the excellent Rest-Assured to confirm that a /helloworld end-point does its "Hello World" business.

```
@Before
public void beforeAll() throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setResourceBase("./web");
    loadAnnotations(context);
    server.setHandler(context);
    server.start();
}

@Test
public void testSomething() {
    when()
        .get("/helloworld")
    .then()
        .statusCode(200)
        .body(equalTo("Hello, world\n"));
}
```

It all works in Intellij, just fine.

Ant barfs though, saying it can't find the servlet API.  It is definitely in the classpath.  I've tried changing the order of the the Jetty jars and servlet-api jar (didn't work). I've tried nixing the servlet jar from the classpath (didn't work). I'm not sure what else I could do, other than push the servlet jar to ant_home/lib/ which would suck.  Advice?

Comment: Do **not** use `jetty-all.jar` in your project, that's not what [it exists for](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg06030.html).

Comment: Jetty-all replaced with the constituent jars individually. Problem as described still remains.

Comment: Jettt-all put back again, as it was nothing to do with why the tests wouldn't run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Ant is a bit cryptic it seems. The root cause has been fixed in https://github.com/paul-hammant/helloworld-war. It was that some jars had to taken out of the regular Ant <classpath/> directives, and put in Ant's lib/ folder itself.

Specifically:

1. hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
2. hamcrest-library-1.3.jar
3. junit-4.12.jar

It is ten years since I last used Ant. I had a hazy memory of something hokey with Junit. It seems in the passage of time, Hamcrest has joined JUnit in needing a hokey setup.